# Install php extension (php_gd2) with FTP only access to server

Tags: php, ftp, php-extension

Is it possible to install an extension of PHP, namely php_gd2, with FTP access only to the server, and the admin role of WordPress?

My research on this tells me it is not possible, but I'm hoping I'm missing something

Comment: It's not possible. Even if you could somehow install the extension into the correct directory (which you probably don't have access to through FTP) and enable it in the php.ini file (which again, you probably don't have access to either), you'd still need to restart the webserver for it to take effect (which you're probably also not allowed to do)

Comment: thanks, that was also my best guess, too bad.